# Implicit differentiation vs. solve then differentiate

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

In a calculus assignment, I was asked to find the derivative of the following:

$$yx^4=\frac{2}{3}$$

Solving for y then differentiating produces:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{-8}{3x^5}$$

The material lists this as the correct answer. However, the two computer algebra systems I've entered this into use implicit differentiation and produce the following solution:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{-4y}{x}$$

Which solution is correct and when should one use implicit differentiation instead of solving for y?

Comment: They’re  the same given what you know about x and y from the original expression.

Comment: Indeed.  $yx^4=2/3$ entails that $\dfrac{-4y}{x}=\dfrac{-8}{3x^5}$ .

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I see it now, thank you!